# Confusion about titanium create new project

Tags: titanium

I am a beginner to titanium
I am supposed to do a titanium project that have a log in page and then I have to show a listview
Now I am very confused about somethings
1-when creating a project, I supposed to choose between "Mobile App Project" and "Mobile Module Project" .. but I don't know what are the differences between them ?

2-In java script code, how can I move between application's windows.
 I mean in native android we write

```
startActivity(new intent(this , ActivityName.class));
```

so what is the equivalent in titanium ?

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are answers to your questions

1)you have to create mobile project not module project for now

2)Here are many listView examples

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView

3)This is how you open a new window in titanium

```
var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
window.open()
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for quick answer ?
If you don't mind :$ I have another question: Should I write all the code and UI of all project in app.js file?

Comment: and I wonder what is the best to use .. Alloy or classic project ?

Comment: Alloy is best and you dont have to write all the code in app.js